# How do I pass a front end value to JavaScript counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass a value from the front end based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994662/count-animation-from-number-a-to-b).

My markup:

```
<h2 id="number">84</h2>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {    
     var range = end - start;
     var current = start;
     var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
     var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
     var obj = document.getElementById(id);
     var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
          if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
          }
        }, stepTime);
      }


      animateValue("number", 0, 84, 5000);
```

So if I enter `<h2 id="number">98</h2>`  it should count up to 98

Comment: Just remove the `end` param and get the number from the `obj` by `Number(innerText)`?

Comment: can you clear your question or add an example?

Comment: @Jervz09 for example <h2 id="number">154</h2> should count up to 154

Comment: Do you mean you need to insert the h2 tag in the body and count up?

Comment: @buzz check my answer !

Comment: @Jervz09 Thanks! I added var end = document.getElementById(end).innerText; and passed the ID in the function. Although I'm using the same param twice I'm sure I'll find a more eloquent way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY IT !!! and Enjoy :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button type="button"
onclick="animateValue()"></button>

<h2 id="number">98</h2>
</body>

</html> 
<script>

function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {    
     var range = end - start;
     var current = start;
     var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
     var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
     var obj = document.getElementById(id);
     var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
          if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
          }
        }, stepTime);
      }

  var x = document.getElementById("number").textContent; //Get number that you want :D
      animateValue("number", 0, x, 5000);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to reuse the function so I ended up doing this: https://jsfiddle.net/buzz868/rc2knhyx/2/