# CSS animation works in chrome but not in firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

I am facing this issue of animation in firefox and safari. Animation is working in chrome.
I tried using -Moz- and -WebKit- vendor prefixes but firefox and safari already have support for animation.

CSS:

```css
.vision-div {
  margin-top: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.vision-grid-div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.visionheading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

.vision-subdiv1-span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12.5rem;
}

.vision-subdiv2-span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12.5rem;
}

.vision-subdiv3-span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12.5rem;
}

.vision-subdiv1-heading {
  animation: counter1 4s 1 forwards linear;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: -1rem;
}

.vision-subdiv1-heading::after {
  content: counter(num);
}

.vision-subdiv2-heading {
  animation: counter2 4s 1 forwards linear;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: -1rem;
}

.vision-subdiv2-heading::after {
  content: counter(num);
}

.vision-subdiv3-heading {
  animation: counter3 4s 1 forwards linear;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: -1rem;
}

.vision-subdiv3-heading::after {
  content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter1 {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 50;
  }
}

@keyframes counter2 {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 14;
  }
}

@keyframes counter3 {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 30;
  }
}

.vision-subdiv1-para {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.vision-subdiv2-para {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.vision-subdiv3-para {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.vision-div-para {
  width: 65%;
  margin-top: 2.8rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<div className="vision-div container">
  <h1 className="visionheading">
    Why you should find a Fitness buddy!
  </h1>

  <div className="vision-grid-div row ">
    <div className="vision-subdiv1 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
      <h4 className="vision-subdiv1-heading">
        <span className="vision-subdiv1-span">%</span>
      </h4>

      <p className="vision-subdiv1-para ">
        People stop working out because of the Lack of Motivation
      </p>
    </div>
    <div className="vision-subdiv2 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 ">
      <h4 className="vision-subdiv2-heading ">
        <span className="vision-subdiv2-span">%</span>
      </h4>
      <p className="vision-subdiv2-para ">
        People stop working out because they are clueless about where to start
      </p>
    </div>
    <div className="vision-subdiv3 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4">
      <h4 className="vision-subdiv3-heading ">
        <span className="vision-subdiv3-span">%</span>
      </h4>
      <p className="vision-subdiv3-para ">
        People are very inconsistent with their workouts
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p className="vision-div-para">
    Data from a Survey done by GymPik in 2019 across 5 metropolitan cities in India with a sample size of 1.6 million people.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please put your example in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I have created a file in code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/example-ry3kz?file=/src/components/App.jsx it is a react file, can u work with a react file?

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the issue is simple, the `@property` is not supported on Firefox or Safari browsers but is supported on Chrome, so you are seeing your animation working on Chrome but not on Safari or Firefox. Here is the [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property) page that clarifies on which browsers the `@property` works.

I recommend checking any new CSS features on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) and see if it is supported in all the browsers that you want to support.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any alternate for @property for firefox and safari?

Comment: I don't think there is an alternate for `@property` as it is a new feature but I think you can use more widely used ways of animating numbers, here's a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994725/13901135) or you can use [css-tricks blog](https://css-tricks.com/animating-number-counters/) on animating numbers.